# Protecting backend password in iOS app bundle

Tags: ios, security, passwords, bundle, backend

I have an iPhone app that will incorporate "liking" / "+1" with a global leaderboard of the highest ranking items. I'm communicating the +1 to the backend server over HTTPS. Additionally I'm using a password so that people can't tamper with the results.

My dilemma is that the password is currently a hardcoded plaintext NSString which can be easily read if a jailbroken user goes looking in the app bundle.

Is the best solution simply to obfuscate the string, and then de-obfuscate it at runtime? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can obfuscate it using a mix of characters C strings and objective-C string making it harder to find :

[See this blog post about it](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/security/security-by-obscurity)

As well you can use some measleading #define directives

But I agree, these are only obfuscation "tricks".

Comment: Thanks—I think I may wind up doing something like this. The link tells me others are dealing with the same issue, which is reassuring! I doubt a malicious person would spend the time to de-obfuscate the string, but I'm curious to see if anyone has an alternate solution. If nothing brilliant comes up, I'll mark yours as the answer!

Comment: Nothing brilliant has come up! This is what I'm going with. Thanks!